# MSAccess Sorting column with text and numbers

Tags: sorting, ms-access, text, numbers

I need to sort a column in my Access2010 Query correctly. It is a Textcolumn containing Strings with numbers like "CRMPPC1". The text length may vary within the column.

When I sort this it looks like

```
CRMPPC1
**CRMPPC10**
CRMPPC2
CRMPPC3
CRMPPC4
....
```

But what I need is

```
CRMPPC1
CRMPPC2
CRMPPC3
CRMPPC4
....
**CRMPPC10**
```

Can anybody help me out (preferably with SQL)? I tried various approaches like VAL, CAST etc. but nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of characters in the text prefix is variable then I don't think there is a pure Access SQL solution, but the VBA function

```
Public Function ExtractNumber(textString As Variant) As Long
Dim s As String, i As Long
s = Nz(textString, "")
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    Select Case Mid(s, i, 1)
        Case "0" To "9"
            Exit For
    End Select
Next
If i > Len(s) Then
    ExtractNumber = 0
Else
    ExtractNumber = Val(Mid(s, i))
End If
End Function
```

would allow you to use a query like this

```
SELECT textTest.*
FROM textTest
ORDER BY ExtractNumber([textColumn]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Found that there are also empty fields in this column. May be handled as 0 for sorting. Any idea how to include that in your code?? Sorry, but i am not too familiar with VBA

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Does the job pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Try out using this 'hack' for natural order sorting.  It only works for two characters, but you can modify it for more of course.

'''' ONLY WORKS WITH LAST TWO CHARACTER NUMBERS AT THE END.  IF YOU HAVE THREE NUMBERS IT WILL BREAK'''''''

Function PadNumberForNatSort(strToMod) As String

```
If IsNumeric(Right(strToMod, 1)) = True Then
    If IsNumeric(Mid(strToMod, Len(strToMod), 1)) = True And IsNumeric(Mid(strToMod, Len(strToMod) - 1, 1)) = True Then
        PadNumberForNatSort = strToMod
    Else
        PadNumberForNatSort = Mid(strToMod, 1, Len(strToMod) - 1) & "0" & Mid(strToMod, Len(strToMod), 1)
    End If
Else
    PadNumberForNatSort = strToMod
End If
```

End Function

In your SQL: ORDER BY PadNumberForNatSort([column_name])